# Is a Turing Machine a Well-formed formula?

Tags: formal-languages, turing-machines, logic

Today i wrote something about the bijection between turing machines and recursive functions. And i describe a Turing Machine as a Well-formed formula because it seems like a WFF to me.
But is it correct when we say that a Turing Machine is a WFF ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes and no. Turing machines *aren't* WFF, but can be encoded as a WFF. The definition of TMs uses sets and functions (which aren't symbols in the alphabet), but its possible to create a one-to-one encoding from TMs to WFF. Usually, given a TM $M$, we refer to its encoding as $\langle M\rangle$.